# How can I use the operator input from fmt.scan to calculate something?

Tags: go, operator-keyword

Is it possible to use fmt.scan to input an operator (+,-,*,/) and use that to calculate something?

for example:

```
fmt.Scan(&operator)

fmt.Println(10-5)          **//instead of this** 

fmt.Println(10,operator,5)  /**/ this**
```

Comment: No, not possible like this. You'll have to handle operators yourself. `if operator == "+" { fmt.Println(10 + 5) }`, etc.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i was trying to build a simpel calculator. And asking the user to input the operator and two numbers to calculate. I managed to fix it with an for statement but i thought maybe i can be done simpeler.

Comment: Hi, it might be a good idea to use a switch statement for allowing input, this will also act as a validation step because you can use a default case to return feedback. What if input was the letter `a` for example?

Comment: No, evaluating arbitrary Go code at runtime is not possible. And in the languages where it is possible (JavaScript, Perl, etc), it is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

#### Understanding operators

An operator is an ASCII character, so you'll have to scan for a string, and test it against your operators to find what operation to achieve.

There is no relation between the "+" string and the addition operation in Golang.

#### Example code

```golang
input := ""
fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)
switch input {
  case "+":
   fmt.Println(a + b)
  case "-":
   fmt.Println(a - b)
  // ...
}
```

This is not the most maintainable code but it shows how to perform what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a map to handle this actually, with a function type declaration

for example:

```
type OperatorCallback map[string]func(float64, float64) float64

...

if fn, ok := operators[op]; ok {
   fn(10, 5)
}
```

For more detailed example:

https://play.golang.org/p/lfw4YJkKZGZ